# Run function for every variable in `df1` as first argument and every variable from `df2` as second argument

Tags: r, dataframe

I have `df1` and `df2` data frames. I have function `cor(d2$LFA_change,d2$CITR_change,method="spearman")` and I need to run that function for every variable in `df1` as first argument and every variable from `df2` as second argument. How can I do it?

Comment: `cor(df1, df2)`